# 404 redirect with .htaccess triggered incorrectly

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

This is really weird. Here is my set up:

- I have my .htaccess file with a 404 redirect in it: `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php` this works fine. In the top of my 404 file I use a php redirect to point back to `www.mysite.com/index.php`
- I have a sub directory with a wordpress installation in it: `www.mysite.com/blog/index.php`
- Whenever I go to my blog the 404 page gets called after the `blog/index.php` page has loaded, however, the redirect to `www.mysite.com/index.php` never gets called. The blog loads up as expected.

Doing some debugging by outputting the current working directory to my error_log it looks like this:

- Land on `www.mysite.com/blog/index.php`: the cwd is `public_html/blog`, then the htaccess ErrorDocument is called and the cwd changes to `public_html/`. Yet I can still view my blog as though nothing has happened.

My main concern is that this will affect my SEO in a big way.

Anyone had any similar problems or any suggestions?

Comment: are you using a separate htaccess file in /blog for wordpress? Also why do a redirect in 404.php? Why just use `ErrorDocument 404 /index.php`?

Comment: Yea, different .htaccess within /blog/. There's no 404 defined in there, removing it makes no difference. The redirect is just for debugging - the 404 page is getting hit but the redirect not fired which seems a bit odd...